# C++ invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, class

I have the following files: main.cpp, class.cpp, class.hpp, student.cpp, student.hpp

Here are the codes:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "class.hpp"


using namespace std;


int main(){
    vector<Student> students;
    vector<Class> classes;

    Class B4( 4, 'B' );
    classes.push_back( B4 );

    Student john( "John", "Boss", B4 );
    students.push_back( john );
    Student marc( "Marc", "Solo", B4 );
    students.push_back( marc );

    marc.printInfo();
    B4.addStudent( marc );

    return 0;
}
```

class.hpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include "student.hpp"

using namespace std;

class Class{
private:
    int number;
    char letter;
    vector<Student> students;

public:
    Class( int, char );

    void addStudent( Student & );
    void printClass();
};
```

class.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.hpp"


Class::Class( int number, char letter ){
    this -> number = number;
    this -> letter = letter;
}


void Class::printClass(){
    cout << this -> number << "." << this -> letter << endl;
}


void Class::addStudent( Student & student ){
    this -> students . push_back( student );
}
```

student.hpp:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Class;

class Student{
private:    
    string name;
    string surname;
    Class* classStudent;

public:
    Student( string name, string surname, Class & );

    void printInfo();
};
```

student.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.hpp"

using namespace std;

Student::Student( string name, string surname, Class & classStudent ){
    this -> name            = name;
    this -> surname         = surname;
    this -> classStudent    = &classStudent;
}

// printInfo
void Student::printInfo(){
    cout << "Name: " << this -> name << "\nSurname: " << this -> surname <<
                    "\nClass:" << this -> classStudent -> printClass() << endl;
}
```

When I compile these files I get the following errors:

```
student.cpp: In member function ‘void Student::printInfo()’:
student.cpp:15:41: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Class’
      "\nClass:" << this -> classStudent -> printClass() << endl;
                                         ^
In file included from student.cpp:2:0:
student.hpp:5:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class Class’
 class Class;
       ^
```

I have never came to the situation like this one: that I need to use first class in the second class and the second class in the first class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
 #include "class.hpp"
```

after

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.hpp"
```

in `student.cpp`, or the compiler won't know what `Class` is.

Comment: I have already done the exactly same thing and I tried it once more now when you just posted this answer and g++ now posts me some strange things. Like redefinition of class etc.. there are plenty of them, I cant even copy it here

Comment: @alik33 Once you include "class.h" you have to also take care of your linkage.

Comment: @alik33: Post the *first* error message.  Once you fix that, the rest will probably go away (or be obvious how to fix).

Comment: `In file included from class.hpp:2:0,
                 from student.cpp:3:
student.hpp:7:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Student’
 class Student{
       ^
In file included from student.cpp:2:0:
student.hpp:7:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Student’
 class Student{
       ^
`

these are the first two errors. By the way @dragosht what do you mean by that? I dont get it

Comment: `class.hpp` includes `students.hpp`. Remove `#include "student.hpp"` from `student.cpp` or add include guard to each header file.

Comment: @MikeCAT I removed `#include "student.hpp"` from `student.cpp` and now I am again getting plenty of strange errors. The first of them is `student.cpp: In member function ‘void Student::printInfo()’:
student.cpp:14:17: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘void’)
      "\nClass:" << this -> classStudent -> printClass() << endl;
                 ^
`. I am not sure why this happens. I have `using namespace std`, `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Your usage of `Student::printClass()` is wrong. Do not try to print its return value of change its function signature to return what to print.

Comment: @MikeCAT I dont know what do you mean with the second sentence.

Comment: Ohh.. I probably know what do you mean but then how can I print that?

Comment: @MikeCAT I have done it, now there is only one error and it says me about using ->: `student.cpp: In member function ‘void Student::printInfo()’:
student.cpp:15:43: error: request for member ‘printClass’ in ‘((Student*)this)->Student::classStudent’, which is of pointer type ‘Class*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
      "\nClass:" << this -> classStudent . printClass() << endl;
                                           ^
`

Comment: The impliementation of `Student::printInfo()` seems changed from correct one to wrong one. Why?

Comment: @MikeCAT Hmm I've just changed from `this -> studentClass -> printClass()` to `this -> studentClass . printClass()`

Comment: @MikeCAT I can't really tell you why. I can just tell you that I changed it due to how I was learned using dot and arrow

Comment: To print, Just call `Student::printInfo()` without trying to print its return value because the function will do the printing for you.

Comment: @MikeCAT Now I am lost. I need to print info of `class Class` so somehow I need to call that function, no?

Comment: You need to call the function, so call it.

Comment: @MikeCAT GREAT! Finally I have done it haha. Thank you very much!